# React project deployment on Vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vercel

I'm trying to deploy my React project on Vercel, these are the errors I'm getting. I've tried installing the same versions and it's still not working.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^13.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   10 more (framer-motion, mdb-react-ui-kit, react-dom, react-icons, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"^4.12.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!     @material-ui/core@"^4.12.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /vercel/.npm/_logs/2024-03-26T06_42_43_667Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /vercel/.npm/_logs/2024-03-26T06_42_43_667Z-debug-0.log
Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1
```

I've tried installing the same versions. I've also uninstalled Node and reinstalled it.

Comment: It looks like you either have to [upgrade MUI to v5](https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/migration-v4/) or downgrade React to v17.